# How to know which item the user is looking at in a list Flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart

I use in my application a list of posts, I would like to know on which item is the user to update a boolean of the post posts.hasBeenSeen = true.

```
List<PostModel> posts = snapshot.data.cast<PostModel>();
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: posts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index)
      {
        return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
            value: posts[index],
            child: PostItem(postModel: posts[index]));
      },
    );
```

[image]

Here for example I want that the boolean is true only for the post 1, because the post 2 has not been seen yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `VisibilityDetector` from [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector). If you wrap all your list items into it, you can detect which items are visible, also the percent of their visibility. So you can set your `hasBeenSeen` value to `true` for each post that at least once became 100% visible (or you can set a lower threshold if you like).

This is a simple example, based on the package's example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:visibility_detector/visibility_detector.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> items = List<String>.generate(1000, (i) => 'Post $i');

  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Posts',
        home: SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Posts'),
          ),
          body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: items.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return VisibilityDetector(
                key: Key('postkey$index'),
                onVisibilityChanged: (visibilityInfo) {
                  var visiblePercentage = visibilityInfo.visibleFraction * 100;
                  debugPrint(
                      'Post ${visibilityInfo.key} is $visiblePercentage% visible');
                },
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 100,
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(items[index]),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        )));
  }
}
```